# How do I make my python program (C-Bos) open only files with ".bos.py" at the end?

Tags: python

So C-Bos has programs that are .py files obv and you can open them through the main program or just open them like any other .py file. And I want it to only recognize files with .bos.py at the end.

I asked ChatGPT but they made it only open files called .bos.py lmao. Oh and when I tried to open files with that (I renamed a program to .bos.py lol) C-Bos just crashed. I am using elif statements for this btw the code (that works) for that is:

```
elif(cmd=="Run"):
    ope = input("file:")
    subprocess.Popen(ope, shell=True)
```

So yeah end of post.

Answer (score 0):

What about usibg `glob` for this? I don't understand what you meant by `opening` (run it or open in notepad, idle) so I copied the `subprocess` line.

```
import glob
import subprocess

for file in glob.glob("*.bos.py"):
    subprocess.Popen(file, shell=True)
```

Comment: @Puppet glob is part of the Standard Library in Python so you do not need to install it

Comment: @Puppet Why can't you use pip? Having trouble installing it?